# How to display Chart with _Layout in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, charts, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have a StepTwo view which passes some info I'll use later to the following ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatedIndicator(string seriesSelect)
{
    wwStartSelected = (int)TempData["wwStartSelected"];
    wwEndSelected = (int)TempData["wwEndSelected"];
    chartTypeSelected = (string)TempData["chartTypeSelected"];

    var testChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Test")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" }).Write();

    return View(testChart);
}
```

Which then passes the chart to the respective view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatedIndicator";
}

<h2>Created Indicator</h2>

<img src="@Url.Action("CreatedIndicator")" />
```

However, the resulting view only shows the chart; the view doesn't show the _Layout with the standard header/footer. How do I fix it such that _Layout gets shown in addition to the chart?

EDIT: I was also able to duplicate the issue by creating a new MVC template project and setting up the following:

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    var testChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Test")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" }).Write();

    return View(testChart);
}
```

About View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

<img src="@Url.Action("About")" />
```

EDIT 2: Image for clarification when using MVC template (note the lack of the paragraph text && template header/footer)
[image]

Comment: From the looks of it it should be showing your layout...are you sure there's no css in the chart that could be overriding the header/footer?

Comment: Yep, even went so far as to create a new MVC project using the template and add the same testChart code into the About ActionResult and view and got the same issue...

Comment: Is this the only view that doesnt render the _layout?

Comment: Yes, _Layout renders just fine on all other Views.

Comment: What's the `Chart` look like? Is it writing directly to stream?

Comment: I edited question to show the resulting view. I'm not sure if the code in question writes directly to stream though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how the chart helper works unfortunately ..

if you want to show the image which is what the chart helper is creating.. you should just add an `<img>` to the view you want to display it in and have a seperate fileresult return the image data for you.

Change your About.cshtml view to

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

<img src="@Url.Action("MyChart")" alt="SimpleChart" />
```

and add this action to your HomeController.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult MyChart()
{
    var testChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Test")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .GetBytes("png");
    return File(testChart, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but after copying the code and double checking there's still the issue of the header/footer/paragraph text not displaying

Comment: did you change your other actions to just return `View()` and not `View(testChart)`?

Comment: Derpa derp. I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

_Layout.cshtml - > lives in Shared Folder.

It should Contain @RenderBody()

This code

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatedIndicator";
}

<h2>Created Indicator</h2>

<img src="@Url.Action("CreatedIndicator")" />
```

is contained in which file in which folder. Looks wrong to me... a soon as you tell me this ill be able to tell where you went wrong.

### **Update**

Update your Home Controller to have

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return view();
}
```

have another Action in your controller for rendering the graph like you have.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatedIndicator()
{  
    var testChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Test")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" }).Write();

    return View(testChart);
}
```

Then in the view for Home\Index you would put

```
<h2>Home Index</h2>
<img src="@Url.Action("CreateIndicator")" />
```

if you want this from another controller then it would be something like

```
<img src="@Url.Action("CreateIndicator","SomeController")" />
```

Hope that's enough to make it clear what i mean.

Comment: /Views/Indicator/CreatedIndicator.cshtml for the View. And yes, the layout does contain @RenderBody(). I also tried the testChart chart code in a new MVC template project in the Home/About ActionResult && View and got the same issue...

Comment: ok worked out what you are doing wrong give me a sec to type it all out. Ill update my answer shortly